# Php check file for a certain text

Tags: php

hello im having trouble with my code, im trying to read myfile for a specific value, if value is found, it will delete only that text value from the file and continue. heres what i got: Aut is part of a form i have, if the value typed in the form is found in the text file, it will write back to that text file and if not it will echo Invalid Token. ALL help is appreciated.

```
<?php

$myfile = "Variables.txt"; /**This part defines my file holding the keys**/
$lines = file($myfile);   
$fn = "DropBox/Dropbox/Public/Licenses.txt"; /**this is where addition/aut are written**/
$file = fopen($fn, "a+");
if( !($fd = fopen("Variables.txt","w")) )
    die("Could not open $file for writing!");


if( !(flock($fd,LOCK_SH)) )
    die("Could not equire exclusive lock on $file!");


for( $i = 0; $lines[$i]; $i++ )
{
if( $_POST['Aut'] == rtrim($lines[$i]) ) /** if the input value in Aut is found in Variables.txt, only that line will be deleted **/
{
    fwrite($file, $_POST['addition']."\n\t"); /** writes addition which is an input variable to the file $file **/
    fwrite($file, $_POST['Aut']."\n\t"); /** the Aut removed from $myfile is also written to $file **/
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid Code"; /** if the codes is invalid, then this is echoed **/
}
}

if( !(flock($fd,LOCK_UN)) )
    die("Could not release lock on $file!");

if( !(fclose($fd)) )
    die("Could not close file pointer for $file!");
?>
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does wrong currently. (Also it looks like you could rather benefit from using a database instead.)

Comment: All my code is doing is accessing the file i want it to access but it deletes everything in it automatically and echos Invalid code like 10 times. and im not sure how to do it using a database

Comment: Well it writes after the key is confirmed so it works, but its deleteing everything else in my file

Comment: (all the other codes stored in the Variables.txt)

Answer (score -1):

Iterating line by line over the file is probably not the best approach. Instead just use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to read it at once:

```
$text = file_get_contents("Variables.txt");
```

And then look only for the lines to replace with a regex ([`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) first, or even just [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) in either case) from your input variable:

```
// prepare for literal regex matching
$aut = preg_quote($_POST["Aut"], "/");

// check for matching line
if (preg_match("/^$aut\s*$/m", $text)) {

    // Remove line and update file
    $file = preg_replace("/^$aut\s*$/m", "", $text);
    file_put_contents("Vars.txt", $file, LOCK_EX);

    // Write new vars to second text file
    file_put_contents("File2.txt", "$Aut \n $Add \n", FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
}

else {
    // Token not found
}
```

That will just replace lines really starting with `$aut` and leave everything else alone.

Note that you still should open both files readable and with LOCK_SH in parallel to the [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) updating with `LOCK_EX`. (I'm not going to elaborate on that, cause that's a problem *you've* chosen to have.)

Comment: well i dont want to replace any text, my mad let me explain myself a lil bit better sorry about that. Ok so im reading the file Variables.txt and writing to $file which is another .txt file. if the variable from my input is found in my Variables.txt. Then only that text is deleted and then Addition and Aut are both written to $file

Comment: Well then use preg_match, an empty replacement text for preg_replace, and instead write the new input vars to your separate file.

Comment: hey sorry im a bit of a noob, can you write how the new code would look like?

Comment: Please  [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28359118/edit) your *question + title* to be more descriptive. Break up the text into a bullet list etc.